# How to get call info from Kamailio

Tags: call, sip, sip-server, kamailio, info

I have setup a Kamailio server and am able to establish calls. I need a way to get call related information like from, to, duration,etc. I have enabled the dialog module in the config but no avail. I am not well versed with config files and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [Modify the config file](http://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/examples%3aaccounting-setup) to log the call related information in kamailio database tables.Here's the link

You have to uncomment the lines in the config file those add columns to database tables.

In addition to this,a web interface [siremis](http://kb.asipto.com/siremis%3ainstall40x%3amain)  for monitoring server can also be installed

Comment: since the link you mentioned is no longer working, here is my suggestion. To get Call information you can best use CDRs  , which can be done in 2 ways

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to blindly know if config is good or bad. However, as general advise, be sure you use dlg_manage() before relaying the INVITE and the other SIP requests related to calls.

For troubleshooting, you can list active dialogs with 'kamctl mi dlg_list' to see if they are correctly tracked or not.

Answer (score 0):

since the link you mentioned is no longer working, here is my suggestion. To get Call information you can best use CDRs  , which can be done in 2 ways

1. set [acc module CDR](https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.1.x/modules/acc.html)  or
2. get dialog variable and send to external CDR processor.

If you want to obtain further more details about dialogs , its routes , scokets , tiemouts etc  then use 
[dialog DB storage](https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.1.x/modules/dialog.html#dialog.p.db_url) , which looks like

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hash_entry       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| hash_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| callid           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from_uri         | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from_tag         | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to_uri           | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to_tag           | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| caller_cseq      | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| callee_cseq      | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| caller_route_set | varchar(512)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| callee_route_set | varchar(512)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| caller_contact   | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| callee_contact   | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| caller_sock      | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| callee_sock      | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state            | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timeout          | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| sflags           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| iflags           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| toroute_name     | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| req_uri          | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| xdata            | varchar(512)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```