# Kamailio server crashing probability

Tags: kamailio

Where kamailio crash log are saved ? and how to get it ? that is when a kamailio get crashed how do  i see that logs in particular file ? How do I come to know that my kamailio is getting crashed ?

Comment: Please check this link: https://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/troubleshooting:corefiles#troubleshooting_crashes_of_your_server

Comment: ok , thank you . Is there any other tutorials are available for recovery of those logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the probability of crash is low; because Kamailio is a well-tested piece of software. But in cases when it happens log files contain a good load of information about it's reason; also Kamailio will generate core dumps for you. You can refer to [this address](https://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/troubleshooting:corefiles#troubleshooting_crashes_of_your_server) to see information about how Kamailio can generate core dumps for you in case of crash. In order to analyze these core-dumps you can use gdb like this:

```
gdb $kamailio_binary $core_file
```

For more information about gdb refer to [this address](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). It worths mentioning that you can even debug you configuration using [debugger module](http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/debugger.html). So if you think something is wrong in your configuration you can use this module.

Comment: Thank you ,very useful . Can you please guide me if you can for storing a failed log . example : If some client call and his/her sip call is getting cut for some reasons . so would I able to store that particular logs in different file ? so that I should not request them to call again to see only that logs.

Comment: You're welcome. Calls are not cut suddenly and for no reason! But if you want to log CDRs you can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183440/how-to-get-call-info-from-kamailio question. When using CDRs remember to add necessary tables and fileds to Kamailio's database.

Comment: @Avanibadheka yes you can write to different log file.. just set the syslog or rsyslog setting for kamailio level log..so it will write kamailio log to different file.